# @BeforeStep method is not called during unit test execution

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-boot-test

I have an `ItemProcessor` which has a `@BeforeStep` method to access the `ExecutionContext`:

```
public class MegaProcessor implements ItemProcessor<String, String> {

    private ExecutionContext context;

    @BeforeStep
    void getExecutionContext(final StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.context = stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
    }

    @Override
    public String process(final String string) throws Exception {
     // ...
    }
}
```

The unit test for this class:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MegaProcessor.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, StepScopeTestExecutionListener.class })
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MegaProcessorTest {

    @Autowired
    private MegaProcessor sut;

    public StepExecution getStepExecution() {
        StepExecution execution = MetaDataInstanceFactory.createStepExecution();
        execution.getExecutionContext().put("data", "yeah");
        return execution;
    }

    @Test
    public void MegaProcessor() throws Exception {
        assertNotNull(sut.process("pew pew"));
    }
}
```

When I debug the test run, `context` is `null` and the `@BeforeStep` method is never called. Why is that and how to achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

> Why is that

If you want to use the `StepScopeTestExecutionListener`, the tested component should be step-scoped (See [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/api/org/springframework/batch/test/StepScopeTestExecutionListener.html)). It's not the case in your example. But this is not the real issue. The real issue is that the method annotated with `@BeforeStep` will be called before the step in which your processor is registered is executed. In your test case, there is no step running so the method is never called.

> how to achieve that?

Since it is a unit test, you can assume the step execution will be passed to your item processor by Spring Batch before running the step and mock/stub it in your unit test. This is how I would unit test the component:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

public class MegaProcessorTest {

    private MegaProcessor sut;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        StepExecution execution = MetaDataInstanceFactory.createStepExecution();
        execution.getExecutionContext().put("data", "yeah");
        sut = new MegaProcessor();
        sut.getExecutionContext(execution); // I would rename getExecutionContext to setExecutionContext
    }

    @Test
    public void MegaProcessor() throws Exception {
        assertNotNull(sut.process("pew pew"));
    }

}
```

The `StepScopeTestExecutionListener` is handy when you have step-scoped components that use late-binding to get values from the step execution context. For example:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemReader<String> itemReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['items']}") String[] items) {
        return new ListItemReader<>(Arrays.asList(items));
}
```

A unit test of this reader would be something like:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.ListItemReader;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListeners;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener;

@ContextConfiguration(classes = StepScopeExecutionListenerSampleTest.MyApplicationContext.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, StepScopeTestExecutionListener.class })
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class StepScopeExecutionListenerSampleTest {

    @Autowired
    private ItemReader<String> sut;

    public StepExecution getStepExecution() {
        StepExecution execution = MetaDataInstanceFactory.createStepExecution();
        execution.getExecutionContext().put("items", new String[] {"foo", "bar"});
        return execution;
    }

    @Test
    public void testItemReader() throws Exception {
        Assert.assertEquals("foo", sut.read());
        Assert.assertEquals("bar", sut.read());
        Assert.assertNull(sut.read());
    }

    @Configuration
    static class MyApplicationContext {

        @Bean
        @StepScope
        public ItemReader<String> itemReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['items']}") String[] items) {
            return new ListItemReader<>(Arrays.asList(items));
        }

        /*
         * Either declare the step scope like the following or annotate the class
         * with `@EnableBatchProcessing` and the step scope will be added automatically
         */
        @Bean
        public static org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope stepScope() {
            org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope stepScope = new org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope();
            stepScope.setAutoProxy(false);
            return stepScope;
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the cleanest example of a bare bones (i.e. not relying on a host of dependencies) spring batch testing. This should go into the spring batch testing documentation! The current documentation [Spring 4.1 test doc site] (https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/testing.html#testing-step-scoped-components) from Spring Batch is hard to understand and does not demonstrate what one is testing.

Comment: no its not help, cuz @Autowired
    private ItemReader<String> sut; will be always null