# JUnit giving NullPointerException on accessing service class stepexecution

Tags: java, junit, mockito, spring-batch, junit4

I have a service class to be tested.

```
public class MyService{
  private final MyConfig myconfig;
  private final WebClient webClient;
  private String result;
  private StepExecution stepExecution;

  @BeforeStep
  public void saveStepExecution(){
    this.stepExecution = stepExecution);
  }

  @AutoWired
  MyService(
    MyConfig myconfig,WebClient webClient) {
    this.myconfig = myconfig;
    this.webClient = webClient;
  }

  public void someMethod(){
    // does some stuff with stepexecution
  }
}
```

My Junit test case is:

```
@Test
public void someTest(){
  MyService myservice = new MyService();
  myservice.someMethod();
}
```

But it gives Null pointer at stepExecution which is obvious. So, how shall I pass stepexecution from JUnit Test method?

Comment: Your code as shown contains several error (e.g. a `)` in `saveStepExecution` and calling a no-arg constructor `MyService()` while no such constructor is defined). Please post a [mre].

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the answer you are looking for. I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment or improve your question but, I fell like your question is similar to this.

[@BeforeStep method is not called during unit test execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52190553/beforestep-method-is-not-called-during-unit-test-execution)

Comment: Solved with help of link you shared, using MetaDataInstanceFactory. Appreciate your time. Thanks

Comment: @usr_11 In this case, please upvote the answer that helped here: stackoverflow.com/a/52192057/5019386. Thank you